# Multiple choice in alert dialog

Tags: android, checkbox, cursor, android-alertdialog

I'm focusing following problem. 
I have an alert dialog with setMultipleChoiceItems, dialog is created 
and shown correctly but when I try to uncheck any of the selected 
items, the item stays checked. 
Here is the snippet of the code:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, 
                        android.R.id.text1, 
                        c, 
                        new String[] {label}, 
                        new int[] {android.R.id.text1} 
            ); 
            AlertDialog dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(context) 
               .setTitle(title) 
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.okBtn, null) 
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancelBtn, null) 
               .setMultiChoiceItems(c,state,label, 
               new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() { 
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, 
                                            boolean isChecked) { 
                                    Log.v("TEST", "onClick(..) called with value " + which +
                                       " / "+ isChecked); 
                            } 
               }) 
               .create(); 
             dialog.show()
```

Althought, method OnMultiChoiceClickListener() is called and in log I 
can see: 
"onClick(..) called with value 2 / false" 
so it says that chosen item is supposed to be FALSE (unchecked) but 
the dialog is not updated and item stays checked. 
Any ideas why it is like this?

Answer (score 0):

Because of this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2998

At least as far as I understand it, you have to update you database when the item is checked/unchecked. Personally, I don't like this idea and for multiple choice lists I use ListArrays instead of cursors:

```
        final Cursor mCursor = mDbAdapter.getAllData();
        final CharSequence[] names = new CharSequence[mCursor.getCount()];
        final boolean[] selected = new boolean[mCursor.getCount()];
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!mCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            names[it] = mCursor.getString(0);
            selected[it] = mCursor.getString(1);                
            mCursor.moveToNext();
        }
        mCursor.close();

        mBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(names, selected, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), names[which] + ": " + ((isChecked) ? "on" : "off"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

It is not the best way to do it, but I don't know any better.